# Is there support for BLOBs in YugabyteDB like in Oracle or Postgres?

Tags: blob, distributed-database, yugabytedb

Since YugabyteDB is a Postgres based implementation, will Postgres large objects( https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/largeobjects.html) work in YSQL?

Answer (score 1):

YugabyteDB currently supports [`BYTEA`](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ysql/datatypes/type_binary/) same as Postgresql. But doesn't have support for Large Objects like Postgresql (splitting the blob internally into chunks). There is a [feature request issue on github](https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/3576) for large object support.