# Does Yugabyte's YSQL support type BLOB?

Tags: yugabytedb

I see that from [Is there support for BLOBs in YugabyteDB like in Oracle or Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60058669/is-there-support-for-blobs-in-yugabytedb-like-in-oracle-or-postgres#60071683), it says `BLOB` type is not supported. It is from two years ago so I am wondering if it's still true.

From https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/3576, I see that the ticket for BLOB support is still open but from https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ycql/type_blob/, it seems like it's supported?

I should mention that I tried to create a table with a column typed `BLOB` but got:

```
create table small_files(file_id bigint, file_size bigint, file_name text, content blob);
ERROR:  type "blob" does not exist
```

Does it just mean that the cloud version of yugabyte supports it, ie using YCQL but not YSQL? Is using `BYTEA` the current alternative for type `BLOB`? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The link you shared (https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ycql/type_blob/) is for YCQL which is based on the Cassandra API (and not YSQL, YugabyteDB's Postgres-compatible API).

Even with YCQL, the blob type is not intended for use for very large objects. For example, unlike BLOBs in Oracle, YCQL blob sizes are generally restricted to 32MB in size (but recommended sizes are 4MB or so). It is not really designed for storing very large objects.

Also at this time YSQL support for BLOBs does not exist in YugabyteDB.

Answer (score 0):

Blobs are supported according to "https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ycql/type_blob/"